# H2's File Locking Method 'Serialized'

Tags: java, database, multithreading, h2

I see some inconsistency in the H2 documentation, according to [h2 features page](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html)

> Database File Locking
>
> [...] The following file locking methods are implemented:
>
> The default method is FILE and uses a watchdog thread to protect the database file. The watchdog reads the lock file each second.
>
> The second method is SOCKET and opens a server socket. The socket method does not require reading the lock file every second. The socket
>   method should only be used if the database files are only accessed by
>   one (and always the same) computer.
>
> The third method is FS. This will use native file locking using FileChannel.lock.
>
> It is also possible to open the database without file locking; in this case it is up to the application to protect the database files.
>   Failing to do so will result in a corrupted database.

From the above it would seem that it's not possible to share a database on a remote file system between different computers without caring manually for concurrency when writing.
In the advanced page however they add a fifth method [file locking serialized](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#file_locking_serialized) which should permit to:

> This locking mode allows to open multiple connections to the same
>   database. The connections may be opened from multiple processes and
>   from different computers. When writing to the database, access is
>   automatically synchronized internally.

Did I get this correct that there's a contradiction? or did I misunderstand file locking serialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [serialized file locking was implemented as an experiment](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#file_locking_serialized), as documented: "This feature is relatively new. When using it for production, please ensure your use case is well tested (if possible with automated test cases)." This is the reason why it was never added to the regular documentation.

I would not recommend sharing a database on a remote file system. Unrelated to H2, I have had bad experiences with NFS implementations. In one case, file locking was broken (after a crash and a restart, files were still locked). In one case, concurrent access was broken (one client did not see changes made by another client) due to a bug in the NFS implementation. In multiple cases, files were closed from time to time because of an unreliable network connection. And in many cases performance was bad. All that might be OK for certain use cases such as sharing office files, pictures or movies. But for a database this is not good.